# Error code: ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_LENGTH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

I have a rails 2.3.8 application that worked just fine until I noticed that I'm not being able to download files from the same due to multiple `Content-Length` headers.
Interesting stuff is when I run the app on development mode everything works fine but when I restart the app on production mode I get this set twice.

Here are two different response headers:

When on production:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 07:33:42 GMT
Server: Mongrel 1.1.5
Status: 200 OK
X-Sendfile: filename.pdf
Content-length: 386742
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="6301 OCCUPANT EMERGENCY PROCEDURES.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 1
Set-Cookie: *******
```

And on dev mode

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 07:58:05 GMT
Server: Mongrel 1.1.5
Status: 200 OK
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Cache-Control: private
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="6301 OCCUPANT EMERGENCY PROCEDURES.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 386742
Set-Cookie: bssonline=f7d1552a46e499430af3367a0144267e; path=/
```

So on the dev mode only one `Content-Length` is found once whereas in the prod mode it comes twice due which Im not able to download any files.

Any idea as to how to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: One has an upper case L on 'length' the other doesn't, you could search your code, case sensitive, for both strings and find the area responsible.

Comment: Wow, I removed it and it works .. thanks a ton 
But now I can download the file but cant open it, the pdf reader says cant open text/plain file while the content-type is application/pdf .. any ideas ?

Comment: Are the files generated by your application or just static files stored and served? If the latter can you manually retrieve one and check that they open?

Comment: They are static files and could be opened but cant be opened after downloading the same.

Comment: Are the filesizes the same between downloaded and manually retrieved versions of the file?

Comment: Looks like file size is the problem. Saw the header and found `Content-Length: 1` which means the size are not the same. But the same code when run on dev mode, it returns header with correct length

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34143/discussion-between-matt-and-pamio-solanky)